# cordova plugin directory creation error Ionic App

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, phonegap-plugins, ngcordova

I am getting the following error on creating a new directory using `ngCordova` file plugin.

```
FileError {code: 12, message: "PATH_EXISTS_ERR"}
```

Comment: You should include the code that creates the error, this will let people look at the path you are using and settings you are using if any

Comment: Thanks, Now the issue is fixed , actually that error comes when we tried to create a new directory with the same name of an existing directory.